# PHPMailer Error - multiple errors

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

```
Could not access file: http://localhost/k/d/filename.pdf
2014-07-28 16:20:10 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
(10060) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

I am trying to send an email. I'm using XAMPP and PHPMailer, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've looked up tons of similar issues, but I can't find my error.

```
require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require 'PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password"; 
$webmaster_email = "username@gmail.com";
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$name=$_POST['email'];
$mail->From = "username@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "User Name";
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['email'],$_POST['email']);
$mail->AddReplyTo("username@gmail.com","User Name");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
$mail->AddAttachment($_POST['file']); 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "sent document";
$mail->Body = "Here is the document you requested. Thank you.";
$mail->AltBody = "Here is the document you requested from myITpc. Thank you.";     
if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

`$_POST['email']` contains an email address, such as `joe.shmo@hotmail.com` and `$_POST['file']` contains a local filepath, like `http://localhost/folder/file.pdf`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sending emails from localhost? Is it configured to handle smtp requests?

Comment: ummm... I'm not sure. I thought I was sending the email from smtp.gmail.com. Sorry, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I caught myself on the same issue, that's why I'm asking - If you have access to a non-local server , put your code there and try sending the email. From my experience localhost doesn't send emails via smtp unless it is specifically configured to do it.

Comment: I suggest you get it working without the file attachment first. For gmail, use `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 587`. If you're attaching a local file, you should be providing a local path, not a URL.